# encryption and decryption time for RSA-crt in java?

Tags: rsa, public-key

I try compute execution time for encrypt and decrypt data has 1024 bit = 128 byte  in RSA-crt algorithm. I need this results. But I believe this result wrong. because big diffrent between execution time for encrypt and execution time for decrypt. My code is following

```
  private void keygen()
{
    p = BigInteger.probablePrime(n/2, random);
    q = BigInteger.probablePrime(n/2, random);

    N=p.multiply(q);

    phi_n=(p.subtract(one)).multiply(q.subtract(one));
    e=new BigInteger("65537");
    while(e.gcd(phi_n).intValue()!=1)
    e=BigInteger.probablePrime(32, random);

    d=e.modInverse(phi_n);
    dp=d.mod(p.subtract(one));
    dq=d.mod(q.subtract(one));
}

private void encrypt()
{
    M=new BigInteger(1024,random);
    C= M.modPow(e,N);
}

private void decrypt() {
    Mp=C.modPow(dp, p);
    Mq=C.modPow(dq, q);

    RM=(((Mp.multiply(q)
        .multiply(q.modInverse(p)))
        .add(Mq.multiply(p)
        .multiply(p.modInverse(q))))
        .mod(N));
}
```

The timing function is

```
for (;;) {
    long begin = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i ++) {
            //function to measure, eg.
        crtrsa.decrypt();
    }
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long time = end - begin;
    if (time >= 2000) {
        System.out.println("average Decryption takes: %.2f ms",(double)time / num);
        break;
    }
    num *= 2;
}
```

On my laptop when run program it give me the follow 
average Key generation takes: 58.60 ms
average Encryption takes: 0.09 ms
average Decryption takes: 1.89 ms
I note big difference between 0.09 ms and 1.89 ms
I want tell me where my  wrong or any link about this issue.